# What does volitional form + か + というNOUN mean

Tags: volitional-form

What is the translation of 「ナイフの10倍は**あろうかという巨大な刀**」.

I think it's translated into "The huge sword that is 10 times bigger than a knife"

And what is　「はあろうかという巨大な刃」.
I'd appreciate it if you could explain it with easy English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ナイフの10倍はあろう**か**という巨大な刀
> (= ナイフの10倍はあるだろうかという巨大な刀)
> the huge sword that is perhaps more than 10 times bigger than a knife

To break down,

- This は is a contrast maker working like "at least".
- あろう is the "volitional" form of ある, but it's roughly the same as あるだろう here. あろう sounds more literary.

  - [Japanese Grammar: The mysterious connection between the volitional form and でしょう / だろう](https://selftaughtjapanese.com/2022/03/30/japanese-grammar-the-mysterious-connection-between-the-volational-form-and-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-deshou-darou/)
  - [推量の助詞、「う」... does this particle exist?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14854/5010)
- This ある is not "to exist" but a verb to express the size/weight of something. See [my answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/97542/5010).
- This か is optional, but it's a question marker that adds a sense of uncertainty (i.e., "perhaps", "presumably"). [See my answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65697/5010).